# Error while creating datalab vm

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

i am following this [datalab quickstarts](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts). when I fire `datalab create devVM` (devVM is the name of cloud datalab vm that I want to create), I am getting following error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.disks.create) Could not fetch resource:
- Invalid value for field 'resource.name': 'devVM-pd'. Must be a match of regex '(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)'
```

can someone please point, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with a name consisting of lower-case letters. I don't think GCE allows VMs/disk names with upper-case characters.

Comment: thanks @nikhil-Kothari to point out. I just missed to read regex in error.